# Overriding configuration is spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here is my situation. I have a parent project which has a bean configuration as follows

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {
@Bean
public BeanA beanA(@Autowired BeanB beanB) {
  return new BeanA(beanB);
}
```

I want to override this configuration, because I need to override some of the definitions on BeanB.

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {
@Bean
public BeanA beanA(@Autowired BeanC beanC) {
  return new BeanA(beanC);
}
```

Where my bean of type C

```
public class BeanC extends BeanB { ... }
```

But when I run the application, I am always getting the configuration coming from the parent. Also have enabled the bean-definition-overriding

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Does anyone knows how can I tell the spring container to use my bean definition instead the one that is coming from my parent project.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have write access to the parent project?

Comment: I have, but the point is that I don't want to change the existing login in the parent project I want to just inject a custom bean instead the default described in the parent

Comment: I've asked this because using `allow-bean-definition-overriding` is considered bad practice since it makes things more complicated. I would recommend you to use `@ ConditionalOnMissingBean` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html) in your parent project, so you can just define a bean in child project and everything should work

Comment: Hey mate thanks a lot, it solves my problem. 
Annotating the bean in the parent project with @ConditionalOnMissingBean was what I really need.

Comment: Why would you need to override it? `BeanC` is a `BeanB` instance, so the only thing you need is to define `BeanC` and Spring will inject that in the place of `BeanB`. If the "old" `BeanB` is still picked up, exclude it from being detected (using an `excludeFilter`) and configure your `BeanC` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your bean with @Primary annotation (see: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-primary)

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

@Primary
@Bean
public BeanA beanA(@Autowired BeanC beanC) {
  return new BeanA(beanC);
}
```